# No input file specified. in Laravel 5 homestead installation

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm learning Laravel and seem to be running into a problem with my paths in my homestead.yaml file but can't seem to figure it out. The error I'm receiving is 'No input file selected.'. I have my hosts file setup, and have tried halting and provisioning, yet I still keep getting this error. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

### yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nsf"

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/homestead.app/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar
```

### Hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/etc/hosts" 11L, 269C
```

### Ping output

```
ping -c 5 192.168.10.10
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.372 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.252 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.307 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.337 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.328 ms

--- 192.168.10.10 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.252/0.319/0.372/0.040 ms
.homestead :>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is almost always caused by either an incorrect web root,
check that `/home/vagrant/Code/homestead.app/public` is the correct path on the homestead box.

or permissions on the `storage` folder, laravel needs write permissions on several of the subfolders in `storage`.

Check that the webserver user has permission to write to that folder.